# Django datetime automatically sets timezone?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form that takes a date. Once the form is validated, however, the time is moved 6 hours. For example, the date that is being recived through a POST method is `[u'01/29/2014 02:58:00']` while after the form is validated the cleaned data for that field is `2014-01-29 02:58:00-06:00`, which gets store as the date I've entered + 6 hours. Am I doing something wrong here? Where might the problem be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a feature of django. You would have `TIME_ZONE` set to `-06:00` in settings and `USE_TZ` is `True`. In such cases django converts date time objects to timezone aware datetime objects.

For how to adjust or show user specific time in his time zone, look at doc of [django timezones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/).